# JavaScript task scheduling, Macrotask and Microtasks

Tags: javascript, event-handling

From [Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/)'s blog

Fiddle (Click on Hey): https://jsfiddle.net/1rpzycLf/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Let's get hold of those elements
var outer = document.querySelector('.outer');
var inner = document.querySelector('.inner');

// Let's listen for attribute changes on the
// outer element
new MutationObserver(function() {
  console.log('mutate');
}).observe(outer, {
  attributes: true
});

// Here's a click listener…
function onClick() {
  console.log('click');

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('timeout');
  }, 0);

  Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    console.log('promise');
  });

  outer.setAttribute('data-random', Math.random());
}

// …which we'll attach to both elements
inner.addEventListener('click', onClick);
outer.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

When running this piece for the `inner div` the results I get are

```
click
mutate
click
mutate
promise
promise
timeout
timeout
```

and I am struggling to see how this is the case.
The Execution should be

1. First Handler (Macrotask)
2. Process **All** Microtasks
3. Second Handler (Macrotask)
4. Process **All** Microtasks
5. SetTimeout (Macrotask)
6. SetTimeout (Macrotask)

With this in mind, I am expecting the log to output instead:

```
click
promise
mutate
click
promise
mutate
timeout
timeout
```

Not sure why `promises` are being executed only after two of the click's event handler has been processed. The very first promise should ideally execute after the first `mutate` but we can see that it is clearly not the case. Anyone know why? (Using firefox 54.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the element, you naturally get `click` outputted first, because you have a click event handler on it, and the log of the word 'click' in the **first** thing to happen in the click event handler function.

Next up is `setTimeout(function() {}, 0);`. This pauses JavaScript's execution, and is like a thread/process yield in C. It doesn't execute until later, so we'll come back to that in a bit.

Because you're not actually doing anything with the promise, it resolves instantly, logging out **second**.

The mutation happens **third** because the DOM is read top-to-bottom, and you are mutating the `data-random` attribute directly after the promise resolves.

Finally, now that the DOM has finished being read, the timeout finishes **fourth**.

The `timeout` gets logged twice from the inner `<div>` due to **[a separate execution context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem)** to where it was called from. This can be seen by the fact that `console.log(this)` inside an `onclick` does **not** provide the same context as `setTimeout(function() {console.log(this)}, 0);`. Due to **[bubbling](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)** in conjunction with the delayed `setTimeout`, it attempts to fire first from the child `<div>`, and then also from the **parent** `<div>` (which you technically clicked on).

Thus, you end up with:

```
click
promise
mutate
timeout
timeout
```

The `click`, `promise` and `mutate` logs will always come one after another, multiplied by the number of elements that you are clicking on simultaneously. The `timeout` logs will always come last.

```js
// Let's get hold of those elements
var outer = document.querySelector('.outer');
var inner = document.querySelector('.inner');

// Let's listen for attribute changes on the
// outer element
new MutationObserver(function() {
  console.log('mutate');
}).observe(outer, {
  attributes: true
});

// Here's a click listener…
function onClick() {
  console.clear(); // Added for clarity
  console.log('click');

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('timeout');
  }, 0);

  Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    console.log('promise');
  });

  outer.setAttribute('data-random', Math.random());
}

// …which we'll attach to both elements
inner.addEventListener('click', onClick);
outer.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

```html
<div class="outer">Outer
  <div class="inner">Inner</div>
</div>
```

Note that different browsers process these differently. I'd **assume** that Chrome (which my answer is based off on) handles this correctly, due to the code logic.

Firefox handles mutations before promises:

```
click
mutate
promise
promise
timeout
timeout
```

Edge handles both mutations and timeouts before promises:

```
click
mutate
timeout
promise
timeout
promise
```

IE can't handle promises at all, throwing a syntax error.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I don't end up with your example. Firefox still logs `click`
`mutate`
`click`
`mutate` first. This happens when clicking `inner` - EDIT Weird, when I run YOUR snippet, it outputs something different. `click`
`mutate`
`promise`
`promise`
`timeout`
`timeout`

Comment: Interesting -- I get different results on other browsers as well. I'll update my answer to cover this.

Comment: Yes, which may be a problem. How do you know which one is correct? I've also edited my example, i am expecting an execution order of `click` `promise` `mutate` - The theoretical one anyway

Comment: I'd say based on what 'should' happen, Chrome seems to have it right. However, that's a very good question/point, and I'd recommend trying to avoid such a situation by simply using just **one** of `promise`, `mutate` and `setTimeout`.

Comment: Indeed, it seems only Chrome has it right at the moment. Thanks.